# use internet connection continuously in android

Tags: android, wakelock

i have a chat application.my code has a thread which manages internet connection.
but after some minutes my thread goes sleep.
I know i should use `WakeLock` to wake CPU and my thread.
but when i use below code , battery usage goes up.

```
if (mWakeLock == null) {
                        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(
                                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                                "NewOnlineSignalingPowerManagerTag");
                    }
                    if (mWifiLock == null) {
                        mWifiLock = wm.createWifiLock(
                                WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL,
                                "NewOnlineSignalingWifiManagerTag");
                    }
                    if (!mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
                        logging.l("mWakeLock.acquire()");
                        mWakeLock.acquire();
                    }
                    if (!mWifiLock.isHeld()) {
                        logging.l("mWifiLock.acquire()");
                        mWifiLock.acquire();
                    }
```

can you prefer me a better way?

Comment: I suggest to remove that wake lock. When user receives reply your app should give a notification to user.

Comment: i know but if user does not use cell phone , thread goes off and TCP Connection disconnect.so you can not receive any data.

Comment: Are you using service for receiving data?

Comment: No....i just use a thread that manage TCP Connection.

Comment: Why dont you put that thread in service in order to continue receiving data.

Comment: i think Services go to sleep too.

Comment: If service sleeps. why media player developers use service? Service won't sleep. It can be stopped by developer or android system.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to manage a internet connection? You don't have to. Use a Android service, and there won't be a thread issue, nor a sleep issue.

Comment: are you sure Service does not go to sleep?

Comment: Yes, it won't. Ofcourse a Service can be terminated by Android if the memory is really low. But usually it doesn't. Also, you should be using Google's GCM (push service), if you are developing a chat application. So the app is automatically invoked, and there is no need of a service too. Its the optimal way for a chat app